# Will compiler optimize out unused arguments of static function?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I have a group of functions that are all declared `static` and `fastcall`. Most of them make use of a pointer to a struct that serves more or less the role of `this` in C++. Some of the functions don't need anything in the struct, but for uniformity sake I want to pass them the pointer anyway. Will the compiler notice that the argument is not used and omit allocating a register to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote this nonsense program to test this. It's got some nonsense code in the function, and calls it several times because otherwise the compiler just inlined the whole function call making the test useless. (It's a strange mix of C and C++ i know.... stupid code, but still works to demonstrate the issue)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct demo
{
    int a;
    char ch;
};

static  void __fastcall func(struct demo* d)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::sort(begin(a), end(a));
    printf("THis is a test");
    printf("Hello world\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
  //  void*p = (void*)&func;
    struct demo d;
    func(&d);
    func(&d);
    func(&d);
    func(&d);
    func(&d);
    func(&d);
    func(&d);
    //printf((const char*)p);
}
```

As written there the function calls compile to this :-

```
    func(&d);
00F61096  call        func (0F61000h)  
    func(&d);
00F6109B  call        func (0F61000h)  
    func(&d);
00F610A0  call        func (0F61000h)  
    func(&d);
00F610A5  call        func (0F61000h)  
    func(&d);
00F610AA  call        func (0F61000h)  
    func(&d);
00F610AF  call        func (0F61000h)  
    func(&d);
00F610B4  call        func (0F61000h)
```

Which shows that the compiler *will indeed omit the parameter* if it's not used.
**However** if I uncomment the two lines there to take the address of the function then things change, it instead generated this :-

```
00C71099  lea         ecx,[esp]  
00C7109C  call        func (0C71000h)  
    func(&d);
00C710A1  lea         ecx,[esp]  
00C710A4  call        func (0C71000h)  
    func(&d);
00C710A9  lea         ecx,[esp]  
00C710AC  call        func (0C71000h)  
    func(&d);
00C710B1  lea         ecx,[esp]  
00C710B4  call        func (0C71000h)
```

Where it DOES send the pointer.

My assumption is that in the first case the compiler is able to prove that if it generated a custom calling convention to the function that there cannot possibly be any user visible effects but in the second case where you take a pointer to the function, the function could be called from another separately compiled module which has no way to know if the parameter is needed or not. Although in this case it wouldn't matter if the register was set or not, in general the compiler needs to stickl to the exact calling pattern so I assume that it generated the most general code and won't use custom calling conventions if it can't prove that it can see all the code that could call the function.

Anyway, to answer the question, no the compiler will not always pass unused parameters in a register but I certainly wouldn't write any code that depends on any specific behavior here as changing unrelated code elsewhere (taking the address of the function), changed that behavior and there is nothing guaranteed by any standard that I can see.

Comment: it makes sense that taking the address of a function does not allow unused parameters to get optimized away, because the function pointer is typed to the function signature, (even when you cast it to void*) and the compiler can't in general be sure if you use it again by some strange magic. +1 for pointing out this issue

Comment: Indeed. I did wonder if with link time code generation the compiler might be able to use the custom calling convention anyway as it could "see" all of the code, but apparently not, at least in the case of my test.

Comment: The main conclusion I'd take from my test is don't rely on this either way around. It may or may not pass the parameter in a register.

Comment: Your test shows that the caller does not populate the register, but it hasn't shown whether or not the callee has allocated one (i.e. whether subsequent arguments are less prone to being spilled onto the stack)

Comment: Many thanks. I think in general the compiler will refrain from changing the call convention when the address of a function is taken because the pointer can jump to different functions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the compiler should warn you about unused function arguments, if you use proper compiler flags (-Wall, for example).I'd recommend to leave arguments that you don't use out of the arguments list, although I'd guess they'd be optimized away. What you could do to make sure, however is compiling your code twice, once with the arguments and once without, and do a `diff` between the binaries and see if they match. I think it should depend on the compiler you use, and the optimization flags.

Cheers,

Andy

Comment: agreed that compiler do optimizes it but checking it using `diff` - one will not be able to check differences ( as execution depends upon many other things that may vary for every execution process, moreover variable initialization wont that that much time

Comment: @sansix if the binaries are equal, why should the behaviour differ?

Comment: By the way - diff b/w binaraies of what? (may be am thinking other way around )

Comment: @sansix sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: your this statement `do a diff between the binaries` - I am asking diff b/w binaries of what? " execution time or ??"

Comment: @sansix diff is a unix tool to compare files. I suggested comparing the compiled programs to see if the code generated (binary file 1) with unused function arguments matches the code generated (binary file 2) without unused arguments. that should be a reliable way to tell if they got optimized away.

Comment: Ohhh got it now, yeah that will be a good approach indeed. +1

Comment: There is no guarantee that any difference found in the binaries is because the argument has been omitted, so I don't think this is reliable at all.

Comment: @JasonD I agree, that a difference will not tell you much. however, I expect to see an equality, and that would be a pretty conclusive result. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can omit argument in function definition. This will give the hint to compiler that perticular argument is not used , It will take benefit of it and optimize code

void func(struct demo *)
{
...
}